# How to change the visibility of a table row in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html-table, row, visibility

I am trying to show/hide rows in a HTML table by javascript. Checking the check box shall show the additional rows, unchecking it shall hide them.

```
<html><body><form><table>
    <tr>
        <td> This row is always visible. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="cbox" type="checkbox" onchange="for(e in document.getElementsByClassName('switchMe')) e.style.display = document.getElementById('cbox').checked ? 'block' : 'none';"/>
            <label for="cbox">Show more …</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="switchMe" style="display: none; ">
        <td> This row will be shown after the user clicks the check box. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="switchMe" style="display: none; ">
        <td> This row too. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> This row is always visible. </td>
    </tr>
</table></form></body></html>
```

However, nothing happens, and I get an `e.style is undefined` error in the console. How do I access the style attribute of the `<tr>` element correctly?

(I first tried putting the rows in question in a `<div>`. That doesn’t give any error, but the rows are always visible, and the `<div>` is absent in Firebug, so it is probably not allowed there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, `for..in` is ideal for iterating over objects but not on NodeList.
- Second, its a bad practice to have change event listener in html. Anyone can change markup using dev tools and manipulate behaviour of your system. You should use `.addEventListener`
- Third, defining a variable without `var` will make it global.

#### Output of `for..in`

```js
var el_list = document.querySelectorAll('.switchMe');
for(var el in el_list){
  console.log(el)
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>This row is always visible.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="cbox" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="cbox">Show more …</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="switchMe" style="display: none; ">
      <td>This row will be shown after the user clicks the check box.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="switchMe" style="display: none; ">
      <td>This row too.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This row is always visible.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

#### Sample

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/hm8kw22a/1/)

```js
document.querySelector('#cbox').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var switchEl = document.querySelectorAll('.switchMe');
  for (var i = 0; i < switchEl.length; i++)
    switchEl[i].style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>This row is always visible.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="cbox" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="cbox">Show more …</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="switchMe" style="display: none; ">
      <td>This row will be shown after the user clicks the check box.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="switchMe" style="display: none; ">
      <td>This row too.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This row is always visible.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. This one works for me: `<input type="checkbox" onchange="var e = document.querySelectorAll('.switchMe'); for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) e[i].style.display = this.checked ? 'table-row' : 'none';"/>`. +1 for `this`, I didn’t knew that works.

Comment: @Paramaeleon Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

You are having an issue with the use of the for...in loop. This isn't really the loop that you should choose for an Array or an (Array like) object, they should only be used for iterating through object keys and properties as they are very slow on array's where there are much faster methods available.

for...in also modifies state so you should have that available eg.

```
const thing = { one: 1, two: 2 }
for (key in thing) {
  console.log(thing[key])
}
```

You are referencing the `thing` from the outer scope inside the loop

I Think this is a better way as you are not dealing with any external state when you do your iteration.

```js
const rows = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('switchMe'))
const cbox = document.getElementById('cbox')

function changeHandler() {
  rows.forEach(row => {
    row.style.display = cbox.checked ? 'block' : 'none'
  })
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>This row is always visible.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="cbox" type="checkbox" onchange="changeHandler()" />
          <label for="cbox">Show more …</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="switchMe" style="display: none; ">
        <td>This row will be shown after the user clicks the check box.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="switchMe" style="display: none; ">
        <td>This row too.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>This row is always visible.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just a pointer, `arrow function` and `array.from` are very powerful tools but are part of ES6 and some old browsers will not support it. Do check their compatibility before using them.

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement what you were trying to do without creating a function as the other answers did would be to do it as shown below.

However this doesn't mean you should do it this way. In practice **definitely** use the other answers shown.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>This row is always visible.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="cbox" type="checkbox" onchange="var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('switchMe'); for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) arr[i].style.display = document.getElementById('cbox').checked ? 'block' : 'none';" />
          <label for="cbox">Show more …</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="switchMe" style="display: none; ">
        <td>This row will be shown after the user clicks the check box.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="switchMe" style="display: none; ">
        <td>This row too.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>This row is always visible.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```